# How to configure db vault for application running in cloud?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a database (oracle) in my server and I have multiple processes which using this database running in Kubernetes in Google Cloud. To establish the connection to the database, I need to add the IP address of my application node to the database vault.

I don't want to add 3 different IPs to the vault instead I want a common IP address. Is there any way to do that? in the real environment, I have more than 100 processes which access the same database.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of ways of doing that. But what you want is some kind of a load balancer or ingress that will translate all of your 3 ip's into 1 IP or a hostname dns.

The easier way of doing that is to create a NGINX instance (do that inside on your kubernetes cluster, it is very easy - https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) and then you can configure your NGINX instance to route your IP's traffic to the NGINX. Then you will use your NGINX Service to access your DB instance. There's an example here - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

But you can look other great solutions too, such as [istio](https://istio.io/) or [traefik](https://traefik.io/)